# How can you add padding between views in a UIScrollView in Swift?

Tags: swift, uikit, scrollview, padding

I have a simple UIScrollView with images. For simplicity it's a scroll view with two image views as subviews. The image views are anchored to each other. Unfortunately, the images are stuck together. I tried adding top padding to each image but it did affect the spacing at all.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/91cmw.jpg

Is there some way to add padding bewteen elements in a scroll view?

Thanks.

Comment: please read and consider this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. please show us your code! it should be reproducable and copyable. this is not a "we write code for you for free"-platform, but a "we help you with your existing code"

Comment: There is no need, it's a simple scroll view with two image views as subviews.

Comment: you did not understand the platform and did not read the link, if your opinion is "there is no need for code!

Comment: You should provide code example to get help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraints are likely not behaving like you expect. My strong suggestion is to use a `UIStackView` instead, and bind it to the scroll view via constraints, but not your images.

```swift
let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.spacing = 8 // or whatever you want

stackView.addArrangedSubview(image1)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(image2)

scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMask = false

// finish the constraints like the first, but for .trailing, .top, and .bottom
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  stackView.leadingAnchor(constraintEqualTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
  ...
])
```

Comment: This works, thanks!